# Need to split sub-string from a string which lies between first ' and second ' - python

Tags: python, string, split

I am having following pandas dataframe column names. I have to simplify the names. I need to split sub-string which lies between first ' and second '.Expected output given below. Need help!

```
  for i in range(len(df.columns)): 
         print(df.columns[i])

     ('date', '')
     ('A Index', 'PX_LAST')
     ('B Index', 'PX_LAST')
     ('C Index', 'PX_LAST')
```

Expected output:

```
'date'
'A Index'
'B Index'
'C Index'
```

This code solved the issue:

```
  str(df.columns[i])[1:].split(',')[0]
```

Thanks for comments.

Comment: Huh? There are no literal `'`s in your data at all; the only single-quotes in the given text are syntactic.

Comment: `str[0][0]` that is a list of tuples, pairs of strings? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  List element access is a basic coding technique.  You already have it for a 1-D list; extend that to 2-D as shown in your learning materials.

Answer (score 0):

If str is a list, or maybe a tuple (**never call a list str** because str is a type in Python). You have a list of tuples.

As such,

```
str[1][0]
```

will get you the first item in the tuple.

```
example = (('a', 'b'), ('c'))
>>> example[0]
('a', 'b')
>>> example[0][0]
'a'
```

Comment: Actually these are pandas dataframe column names. I have to simplify the names

`for i in range(len(df.columns)):`  
          `print(df.columns[i])`

Comment: it would be helpful to mention that you are working with pandas and data frames in this case.  [Check this and revise your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Well my idea is :

```
for i in range(5):
    x = str[i][0]
    print "'"+x+"'"
```